# Comment inclure des publications ou diplômes obtenus dans un cv français?

Tags: traduction, anglais, curriculum-vitae

Je suis en train d'écrire un cv en français. Je ne sais pas comment je fais pour inclure des publications ou diplômes obtenus qui sont officiellement en anglais:

1. *Texte officiel en anglais* - non: je préfère au moins inclure la traduction française.
2. *Traduction en français* - non: je veux aussi mentionner le titre officiel.
3. *Texte officiel en anglais (Traduction en français)*
4. *Traduction en français (Texte officiel en anglais)*

Si on considère que les options 3 et 4: faut-il d'abord mentionner le texte officiel en anglais et puis la traduction ou faire l'inverse?

Comment: Pour avoir fait un CV en anglais à partir de mon CV français, et n'ayant eu aucun retour (ni négatif, ni positif cependant) sur la forme de mon CV, je conseille de marquer dans la langue d'origine en premier, puis de traduire ensuite. Ce n'est que mon avis, voilà pourquoi je commente au lieu de répondre. (j'ai quand même été pris pour un stage dans l'entreprise à laquelle j'ai envoyé mon CV anglais)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'option 3 me paraît la plus appropriée, d'expérience.Tu cites ta source, en fait, et ensuite tu expliques ce qu'elle signifie (dans le cas où c'est nécessaire), si c'est possible.

Answer (score 3):

Je dirais que tout dépend de la destination du CV.

Si le poste convoité nécessite de connaître l'anglais, alors je me passerais de traduction en français (option 1) ; Ça ouvre la porte à un entretien d'embauche bilingue. Sinon, l'option 3 me paraît plus appropriée, original d'abord et traduction ensuite.

Si j'avais des publications en italien, pour un poste sans besoin en italien, je choisirais aussi l'option 3.

Si le poste est orienté international, je mettrais chacune de mes expériences dans leur langue d'origine, sans traduction.

Comment: J'ai un doute, dit-on "sans besoin en italien" ou "sans besoin d'italien"? J'apprends la langue, merci par avance.